# HighChart: add data series dynamically with dynamically added categories on yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've run into an interesting issue where I cannot add a point with an xAxis of type 'datetime' and a yAxis with dynamic categories and dynamically added series's

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        drawScatter();
        $('#addSeries').on('click', function() {
            //first check if value is already a series
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var id = document.getElementById('txtValue').value;
            getSeriesIndexByEventID(eventid, function(index) {
                //if it doesnt exist, add it to chart
                if (index == -1) {
                    categories.push(id + ' category');
                    console.log(categories);
                    chart.yAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
                    idSeries.push({name: id+ 'n', data: [categories.length-1, [{x: currentDate.getTime()}]]});
                    chart.addSeries(idSeries[idSeries.length-1]);
                    console.log(chart.series[categories.length-1]);
                }
            });
        });
    }):
```

Here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5L59r1qt/10/

I want to be able to click the button and with the text inside add it as a series. It does that but it won't do the correct time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect data array in the addSeries. It should be object with x/y values.

```
 idSeries.push({name: id+ 'n', data: [{x: currentDate.getTime(),y:categories.length-1}]});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5L59r1qt/12/